# Is there a way too pass Jupyter Lab arguments through JupyterHub?

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

Looking to pass in `--LabApp.allowed_extensions_uris=...` when starting jupyter lab ontop of jupyter hub. It does not pick this up, or `--LabServerApp` either.

Whats the correct way to propagate Jupyter lab arguments through Jupyter hub?